# Copy files from one location to many on Linux

Tags: linux

I have six 12TB USB 3.0 hard drives connected to a RHEL 8 box.  One of them is full of files, the others empty.  Is there a software package that will read the files from the full one once and write them to all the others at the same time?

So when complete, all the files will be on all the drives.  `cp` takes over two days to make a single copy.  `md5sum` can read all the data off the source drive in about 18 hours.

Never underestimate the bandwidth of a station wagon full of tapes hurtling down the highway.
–Andrew Tanenbaum, 1981

Comment: Just to make sure you didn't forget to point out one requirement (or more): after that action, **all** your disks would be full. Is that really what you're attempting? Or are you rather looking to "load balance" (i.e. spreading the files equally)? In the first case (make them all full), first thought coming up is software used to duplicate USB sticks for contribution, writing disk images to multiple connected USB sticks at once. I vaguely remember having read about such a while ago.

Comment: You probably don't literally want all the files to be written at the same time (the more files that are being written at once, the slower it's probably going to be); it would likely be better to have a script do it one at a time (but where you don't have to worry about initiating it another time).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Most USB hard drives are NTFS
- RHEL 8 uses NTFS-3G by default
- NTFS-3G is notoriously slow, especially on writes
- `-o big_writes` helps
- Bypassing NTFS-3G by copying bytes instead of files would be a lot faster
- [dc3dd](https://sourceforge.net/projects/dc3dd/) and [dcfldd](https://github.com/resurrecting-open-source-projects/dcfldd) both support multiple simultaneous destinations and are in EPEL.
  Both were developed by the US Department of Defense based on GNU dd.  dc3dd is a patch for the current version of dd.  dcfldd is a fork of an old version of dd.
- Example: `dc3dd if=/dev/sdc1 of=/dev/sdd1 of=/dev/sde1 of=/dev/sdf1`
- After copying a ntfs partition, use `ntfslabel --new-serial` on all copies